# Deploying Django to AWS - WSGIPath refers to a file that does not exist

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I've been struggling with getting Django and AWS to work together. I'm following the tutorial here:

https://realpython.com/blog/python/deploying-a-django-app-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

I've been following all the tutorial steps, including using the "eb option" command to change the WSGIPath, but I keep getting the error:

"ERROR: Your WSGIPath refers to a file that does not exist."

As far as I can tell I've been doing everything exactly according to the tutorial.

The relevant part of my config file looks like this:

```
NumProcesses: '1'
NumThreads: '15'
StaticFiles: /static/=static/
WSGIPath: iotd/iotd/wsgi.py
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: After struggling with this for days, I think this suggestion will come in very handy to anyone having such an issue. Check your logs (last 100 lines is enough) and scan for the attempt to find the WSGI file. In my case, the WSGI path ended up being proj/proj/proj/wsgi.py

Comment: not exactly related but if someone is looking for the updated article on this, found 1 mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62058404/aws-eb-unresolved-resource-dependencies/62270480#62270480

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have read the realpython blog post that you referred to. I would also refer you to the AWS tutorial. It is written for the deployment of a bare bones Django project and it can be found at:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html#python-django-configure-for-eb

I found it useful to work through, and learned a great deal fixing the error you have identified. Of course the fix is related to my own implementation of the tutorial, which I followed step-by-step. I have read other posts that talk to this issue, but the solution stated here was not provided in those posts, as far as I can tell.

An abbreviated version of the tutorial follows to provide some context for the comments made here. This abbreviated version begins after creating/activating the virtual environment, but before its activation.

```
$ mkdir ed_django_app
$ . venv/Scripts/activate
(venv)[~eb_django_app]$ django-admin startproject django_eb
(venv)[~eb_django_app/django_eb]$ python manage.py migrate
(venv)[~eb_django_app/django_eb]$ python manage.py runserver
(venv)[~eb_django_app]$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
(venv)[~eb_django_app]$ deactivate
[~eb_django_app]$ eb init –region us-east-1
```

After the "eb init" command the .elasticbeanstalk directory, along with some files, are created in the initialization process. In that directory you will find the config.yml file. Its contents are:

```
branch-defaults:
  default:
    environment: eb-django-dev
global:
  application_name: eb_django_app
  default_ec2_keyname: myec2keyname
  default_platform: Python 2.7
  default_region: us-east-1
  profile: eb-cli
  sc: null
```

The tutorial directs the developer to then create a directory called .ebextensions and create the 01-eb_django.config file:

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "django_eb.settings"
    PYTHONPATH: "/opt/python/current/app/django_eb:$PYTHONPATH"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: "django_eb/django_eb/wsgi.py"
```

This is YAML and the indentation matters. At least 1 space indent. In this case there are 2 spaces of indent at each level. The WSGIPath is set correctly. It is important to make sure the directory structure is the same as what is indicated in the tutorial.

In the tutorial the "eb create" command is now issued, and as you noted, the following arises:

ERROR: WSGIPath refers to a file that does not exist

The problem that was identified existed in the config.yml where there is the key-pair for application_name:

```
global:
  application_name: eb_django_app
```

It was changed to:

```
global:
  application_name: django_eb
```

This resolved the ERROR for me.

Comment: We had a problem with psycopg2 not installed. adding those file to our .ebextensions/01-app.config:
packages:
  yum:
    postgresql93-devel: []

Comment: I did this tutorial and stuck at forgetting to git commit the changes to ".ebextensions/01-app.config" .
After the git commit and "eb deploy", everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 12):

One thing I found when I encountered this error, is that if your repository is a git repository your .ebextensions folder must be tracked and committed otherwise it will not be picked up properly on eb deploy.

Comment: this this this.  I had to re-discover this twice now.  Odd that I don't see it in docs anywhere, unless it's somehow not seen as common to use git along with your server code deopled EB?  Odd

Comment: Wow, nice catch! The same is true for requirements.txt file. I never would have guessed this as the issue. The documentation page redirects you to the "Using EB CLI with git" page but it's not very clear that requirement.txt needs to be in the git repository as well.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was stuck on this. I figured it had to be git because that was the only thing I changed. I did `git init`, specified `.ebextensions` within `.gitignore`, then did `eb deploy` and got this error.

Answer (score 2):

Using `eb` :

`eb config`

Go to `aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:` and change WSGIPath from:

`application.py`

to

`mysite/wsgi.py`

With "mysite" being your application name ofcourse

Comment: i'm still get same error "Your WSGIPath refers to a file that does not exist."

Comment: You should have a wsgi.py file in your main app i.e. where you settings.py file is located. Use that path. If you don't have the wsgi then that is your problem...

Comment: Why are you using forward slash syntax and not dot syntax?

Comment: @AlxVallejo the forward slash is just the directory of your App

Comment: If you following the tutorial at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html and getting this error, then this is the solution as of right now.

Answer (score 1):

possible solution error : Your WSGIPath refers to a file that does not exist

after following this tutorial:
https://realpython.com/deploying-a-django-app-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

I got the error when I was uploading my protect to aws.
The step that I forgot was to activate my virtual env and from my there type the command 'eb deploy'

note : this error can also occur in different circumstances

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @Zoe - Not sure this is a link-only answer, since the answer specifically indicates the step necessary to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This in django.config file, say your app name is 'yourappname',
worked for me.

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: yourappname.wsgi:application
```